# Excel: Calculating loan amount including interest, when the interest rate increases with the loan amount

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In Excel, I am trying to calculate the loan amount needed, inclusive of the interest repayments. For example, I would need to borrow $105.26 if the interest rate is 5% and I need to have $100 remaining at the end of the first period `P/(1-r)`.

My complication is that in my example, the interest rate is dynamic. As the loan goes up, the interest rate goes up as well. In the example above, the interest rate for $105 would be higher than for $100. I know the interest rate formula is

`[0.013 x EXP(0.1 x {FINALAMOUNT} / 200000000 x 2.25)]`

I am using this to calculate repayments on values that are in the billions.

I can't work out how to calculate the loan amount needed to achieve a known final amount with interest rates that increase with borrowing.

Hope this makes sense, and would appreciate any help!

Comment: Please show us what you've tried and explain how it fails to achieve the desired result

Comment: Sounds like you kind of have to work backwards and use a formula that can calculate number of days principal is within your different interest tiers. I'm not sure a single formula could do that, but maybe consider creating a table that has daily interest calculations, that would grab the correct interest rate per row...

Comment: Thanks both. I ended up conceding at just using the interest rate at the first borrowing amount (e.g. the $100 rate rather than the $105 rate). This was sufficient for my purposes (high-level rather than exact) and the time sensitivity of the project. For those that are interested, there would be alternatives in VBA or potentially exploring Excel's new Lamba function for recursive formulas